# Does a book recommendation website exist?

Tags: webapp-rec

Does anybody know a web service that allows you to

- insert the books you have
- mark authors you like
- mark book series you like
- rate books
- write reviews
- automatically find people who read similar books
- insert the languages you know
- gives, based on this information, recommendations for interesting books
- generate an rss-feed / send emails for some events, e.g.

  - an author you like wrote a new book
  - a serie you like got a new book
  - a book you marked got translated in your language

(and perhaps save your information for usage out of this system)

I only know amazon and some other book stores that offer some recommendations, but I don't know any service that allows me to keep track of the books an author writes.

Do you know a web service like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do most of that on [goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/).  Check out their [How It Works](http://www.goodreads.com/about/how_it_works) page to see how to sign up, add your books, get recommendations, etc.